# Python SpiDev TypeError

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, spi

I have installed spi by the following steps

```
mkdir python-spi
cd python-spi
wget https://raw.github.com/doceme/py-spidev/master/setup.py
wget https://raw.github.com/doceme/py-spidev/master/spidev_module.c
sudo python setup.py install
```

I commented out the long_description line from the setup.py and the installation completed. Now when I run the code for example

```
import spidev
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.mode = 1
```

when the last line spi.mode = 1 is executed im given a error

```
TypeError: The mode attribute must be an integer
```

Any Guesses?

Comment: If you check the [link](https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev/blob/master/spidev_module.c), `SpiDev_set_mode` takes a PyLongObject as an argument. So, to pass it as PyLongObect, you need to do something like `PyObject* val;` and then `val = 1` as in the [link](https://www.logilab.org/268419)

Answer (score 0):

As @Vaulstein points out, this is likely an error in the `spidev` module.  The code is expecting a `long`, but:

```
>>> type(1)
<type 'int'>
```

You can work around this like this:

```
>>> s.mode = long(1)
```

You should probably [open an issue](https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev/issues) on GitHub to report this error.

**Update** I just submitted [a pull request](https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev/pull/27) that corrects this problem.

Comment: The pull request has been merged, so if you refresh your local copy you should be all set.  Incidentally, I suggest just using `git clone` rather than copying over individual files.